# How to Open a Popup on Devexpress Gridview CustomButton Click?

Tags: asp.net, popup, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a **Devexpress Gridview**. I generated a `GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton` in that Gridview on server side.

```
GridViewCommandColumn coldescriptor = new GridViewCommandColumn();                                              
GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton CusButton = new GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton();
CusButton.ID = "btnPopup";
coldescriptor.VisibleIndex = 2; 
CusButton.Image.Url = "~/Images/color2.jpg";
coldescriptor.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;                        
coldescriptor.CustomButtons.Add(CusButton);
ggc_preview.Columns.Add(coldescriptor);
```

On that Custom button click, I need to open a **popup** either by devexpress popup control or any other means.
Inside that popup control I need to load some controls dynamically.

How can I open popup on `GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton` click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the following steps to accomplish this task:

- Handle the client-side CustomButtonClick event;
- Show the ASPxPopupControl via the client-side Show method.

I usually use [DevExpress Search service](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/SearchResults.aspx#cD1UNHxQNXw1N3NlYXJjaHRleHQ9QVNQeEdyaWRWaWV3IFNob3cgQVNQeFBvcHVwQ29udHJvbCBDdXN0b20gQnV0dG9u) for such questions.

```
ggc_preview.ClientSideEvents.CustomButtonClick = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ if(e.buttonID = 'btnPopup') {0}.Show(); }}", ASPxPopupControl_ClientInstanceName_Here);
```

Comment: Hi, When i have clicked custom button  i want to handle popup control to bind  data on server side. Have you  any suggestion ?

Comment: I suggest that you contact DevExpress support regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

First you should attach an event handler to the custom button for the click event. Then in the click event you can go many ways. You can simply show some SuperToolTip from  DevExpress when you only need to display data in some form or another. Not very familiar with ASP.NET, but I assume there are some nice alternatives out there to show pop-ups.

But first a Click event handler for the button ;)

[Maybe this link might provide you with some more information](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18387.aspx).

Comment: I have added a callbackevent for that custom button like this, but how can i open popup inside that event.                   '<ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="gridCallBack(s,e);" />'